# "Would" and "likely" together

Tags: grammar

> 1) **Would** a fatally ill person be **likely** to sleep with the
>   window open on a freezing cold night?

I suppose that modal **would** in this case has the same meaning that word **likely**. Why both this words are used in this sentense?

> 2) What doesn’t make sense is the object the behavior’s directed
>   **towards**.

Why "**towards**" at the end of a sentence?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple distinct questions in a single question post. Use the [edit] button to edit your post. Don't forget to change the title so that people may know what the question is generally about without having to read it (that's what titles are for).

Comment: Surely a fatally ill person is dead?

Comment: As far as I remember, yes.

Comment: [*Would*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/would) and [*likely*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/likely) do not have the same meaning, and there is nothing redundant about using both in the same sentence. *Would a fatally ill person be [likely / unlikely / inclined / uninclined / wise / unwise] to sleep with the window open on a freezing cold night?*

Comment: Is 'fatally ill' ever used? 'Fatal' and 'fatally' are used about outcomes, and for something to be fatal, one or more persons has to have died. A fatally wounded soldier or e.g. victim of a motor accident is dead. A mortally wounded or ill person may be still alive, but, if so, is not expected to live for much longer. Dead people don't, except figuratively,  'sleep', and also don't care much about windows being left open, as far as I know. I would use 'terminally ill'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-china-51176409: "Age remains the strongest risk factor for becoming severely or fatally ill with coronavirus, say experts." (the author is a "qualified doctor and health journalist" according to [this](https://uk.linkedin.com/in/michelle-roberts-927ba310)) and other websites suggest it's okay to use *fatally ill*, but the Google Ngram Viewer indeed prefers *terminally ill* to *fatally ill*, and so does [GloWbE](https://www.english-corpora.org/glowbe/?c=glowbe&q=88195961).

Comment: "Fatally ill" is unusual in British usage, I would say.